# C++ Winsock Will Freeze Receiving Data

Tags: c++, windows

I'm making a program with Code::Blocks in C++ To Send and Receive data with Winsocks but when I try to receive data my program freezes, please help. I don't know why?
I was able to get just 1 line without using a loop so I added a loop to see if I could get more lines that come in, and now it just freezes.

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <windows.h>
#include "resource.h"
#include <winsock.h>

using namespace std;

SOCKET mysocket;
SOCKADDR_IN SockAddr;
char buf1[120];
char buf2[120];
char ReadIp[120];
int UsePort;
int n;

HINSTANCE hInst;

BOOL CALLBACK DialogProc(HWND hwndDlg, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(uMsg)
    {
        case WM_INITDIALOG:
            WSADATA WsaDat;
            WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(1,1), &WsaDat);
            mysocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
            return TRUE;

        case WM_CLOSE:
            EndDialog(hwndDlg, 0);
            return TRUE;

        case WM_COMMAND:
            switch(LOWORD(wParam))
            {
                case IDC_BTN_QUIT:
                    EndDialog(hwndDlg, 0);
                    return TRUE;

                case BtnSend:
                    GetDlgItemText(hwndDlg, PacketText, buf2, sizeof(buf2));
                    send(mysocket, buf2, sizeof(buf2), 0);
                    return TRUE;

                case IDC_BTN_TEST:
                    UsePort = GetDlgItemInt(hwndDlg, PortText, NULL, FALSE);
                    GetDlgItemText(hwndDlg, IpText, ReadIp, sizeof(ReadIp));
                    SockAddr.sin_port = htons(UsePort);
                    SockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(ReadIp);
                    SockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
                    connect(mysocket, (SOCKADDR *)(&SockAddr), sizeof(SockAddr));
                    do {
                        n = recv(mysocket, buf1, sizeof(buf1), 0);
                    if (n > 0)
                        SetDlgItemText(hwndDlg, List1, buf1);
                    } while (n > 0);
                    return TRUE;
                    }
    }

    return FALSE;
}


int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
    hInst = hInstance;

    // The user interface is a modal dialog box
    return DialogBox(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(DLG_MAIN), NULL, (DLGPROC)DialogProc);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It freezes because it's waiting for data. If you don't want to wait for data, don't make a Winsock call that does that. Use one of the many non-blocking I/O methods available on Windows such as [Async operations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741540%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [I/O completion ports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365198%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or completion events.

By the way, your code seems badly broken in many ways. It seems to be missing a *protocol*. You can't use TCP without designing and implementing a protocol on top of TCP. You will get totally unreliable behavior if you don't process the data you've received through some sort of protocol engine that reconstructs the transmitted information. For example, in your case, if someone sends "foo", the final text will depend on how the data got assembled for transport. It might be "foo", but it might be "o" since the "fo" can be overwritten.

If the other side is sending *lines*, as you claim, you need to code this end to *receive* lines. That is, you need to keep receiving data until you have a line and not let later receive overwrite earlier receives so that you can re-assemble the transmitted line. The code to actually implement the receiving of lines is totally missing in the code you pasted. (If, for example, a "line" is defined as a bunch of bytes terminated by a newline character, there needs to be code to search for the newline characters and assemble everything before them into a single buffer for processing.)

Comment: can u post an example of one of those

Comment: It's not likely to be useful to you if I guess at what to give you. What's your outer problem? Are you trying to make a server or a client? Is your process multi-threaded? How important is performance relative to ease of coding? You should start by looking at [WSAAsyncSelect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741540%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It's good for single-threaded, low-performance, Windows event loop clients.

Comment: Thats the whole code its simple like the command in windows Telnet just connects and can receive and send, can be used to read packets also. Im looking at Cases like FD_READ looks useless though.

Comment: Actually, [telnet](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc854.txt) is not simple at all and has an entire protocol including a line parser. You're missing the implementation of whatever protocol you are intending to implement. Your code keeps throwing data away though and that needs to be fixed.

Comment: i ben looking though c++ Winsocks all day though google, mine look allmost the same as all of them, Most are written as command line programs though, that must be why i cant get the recieving to work lol, im yet to see a good example written with a gui.

Comment: That's not the problem. The problem is that you don't have a protocol to implement. If the other side is sending lines, you need code to receive lines. If the other side is sending arbitrary chunks, you need code to reassemble those chunks. You just randomly overwrite previous bytes with new ones willy-nilly. Also, you block in the receive even if you have no reason to think the other side is going to send you any data.

Comment: o overwriting the old bytes dont matter im doind this to test it, when i get it to work in gonna add it all to a Listbox so i can select witch packet i want to Send.

Comment: They're not packets. They're just arbitrary chunks of bytes. TCP is a byte-stream protocol. It doesn't present packets or datagrams to the application.

Comment: ive actually made this before on Vb6 theirs a function i used on their to recieve Private Sub Winsock1_DataArrival(ByVal bytesTotal As Long)
    Winsock1.GetData GetPacket, vbString, bytesTotal
    List1.AddItem GetPacket
End Sub

Comment: its an old game the packets look like this: :SR102;-jH?9I#%G$3].-20PC\OHKTW6%:).\09 D,K1B

Comment: Well, whatever this protocol's definition of a "packet" is, the TCP stack has no idea. If you want to separate the data into packets, you have to actually write the code to do that. TCP does not present a packet interface to the application layer but only a byte stream layer.